# UINavigationBar in UIViewController auto set height when StatusBar is visible?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uiview

Using a `UIViewController` I put a `UINavigationBar` at the top.

When The Status bar is visible the UINavigationBar should get the additional 20px in height. If the statusbar is gone the UINavigationBar should loose the 20px in height.

**Is there a way to set this behaviour automatically?**

Comment: wat do u mean automatically?

Comment: @T_77 that the NavigationBar grows when the Status bar is shown and it shrinks when the StatusBar is gone. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to have this behavior automatically. Use `UINavigationController`. There is no reason to reinvent the wheel when you have a system class suited for your need.

Comment: Can I set custom Views for the left center and right side in UINavigationController?

Comment: Do you mean as bar buttons? Yes, you can.

Comment: Not Only as button I want to set it like in the Twitter app the in app browsers header.

Comment: Yes, you can. Set the `titleView` property of your controller's `navigationItem`.